# Fitting gaussian curve to histogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram, gaussian, data-fitting

I have a data set in excel so I passed it to MATLAB to draw a histogram and append gaussian fitting. My code is below.

```
vData = xlsread("2.xlsx");
figure(1);
hHist = histogram(vData, -2.7:0.001:-2.4);
```

As I run my code, I get a histogram like this 
[histogram of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaG8d.png)

To gaussian fit my histogram, I add some code like this

```
figure(2);
histfit(vData); % I'm not sure this is the right fitting method
```

But the result I got is like this
[fitting on histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZiUH.png)

I guess the bin size and bin edge is not appropriate for my data because my data is usually clustered around -2.5.
hisfit method doesn't have bin size or bin edge parameter so I think I can't use this method. 
I'm wondering how I can get an appropriate gaussian fitting to my histogram. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you have an extreme outlier in your data? What is `max(vData)`? If yes, removing the outlier(s) would solve your issue.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help!